# Passing member function that accepts Base type to class that owns Derived type

Tags: c++11, templates, overloading, pointer-to-member

**Example**

In example above I've tried to store pointer-to-member_function of the overloaded function in the template-based class.
The problem is that overloaded function uses Base class as parameter and current class is template class from Derived class.

**Handlers**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class HandlerA
{
public:
    void foo(const std::string& m)
    {
        std::cout << "HandlerA: " << m << '\n';
    }
};

class IBaseHandlerB
{
public:
    virtual void bar(const std::string& m) = 0;
};

class HandlerB : public IBaseHandlerB
{
public:
    virtual void bar(const std::string& m) override
    {
        std::cout << "HandlerB: " << m << '\n';
    }
};
```

**Events**

```
class Event
{
public:
    virtual void write(HandlerA&) const = 0;
    virtual void write(IBaseHandlerB&) const = 0;
};

class FancyEvent : public Event
{
public:
    virtual void write(HandlerA& h) const override
    {
        h.foo("FancyEvent");
    }

    virtual void write(IBaseHandlerB& h) const override
    {
        h.bar("FancyEvent");
    }
};
```

**Wrapper and usage example**

```
template <typename T, typename Event>
class HandlerWrapper
{
public:
    HandlerWrapper(T&& handler, void(Event::*func)(T&) const)
    : m_handlerImpl(std::forward<T>(handler))
    , m_eventFn(func) {}

    void call(const Event& event)
    {
        (event.*m_eventFn)(m_handlerImpl);
    }

private:
    T m_handlerImpl;
    void(Event::*m_eventFn)(T&) const;
};

// ------- Usage -------
int main(void)
{
    FancyEvent event;

    // OK
    HandlerWrapper<HandlerA, Event> h(HandlerA(), &Event::write);
    h.call(event);

    // Error: Candidate constructor not viable: no overload of 
    // 'writeWithHandler' matching 
    // 'void (LogEvent::*)(CEFEventHandler &) const' for 2nd argument
    HandlerWrapper<HandlerB, Event> h2(HandlerB(), &Event::write);
    h2.call(event);

    return 0;
}
```

**Question**

How to specify correct template type to accept function-to-Base if class template argument is derived from that Base?

My goal is to pass just pointer-to-member_function to another class whenever that class is the same with type that function accepts or derived from it.

Comment: You can greatly simplify our task by providing an example that we can copy/paste and compile. Also it would be easier to deal with simpler class names instead of your domain specific ones, in other words please try to minimise and simplify your example, and make it complete: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Don't add junk into your post. It's bad

Comment: Added compilable code

Comment: your question really could use some improvement... The most important thing is that you can't store function of two different signatures in a single variable... the solution for your original code could make use of some sfinae like [this](https://wandbox.org/permlink/3T37vJs588Qz9AlE)

Comment: I dont want to store  two different signatures in a single variable.
I want to deduce correct signature and store one or another pointer in the ivar

Comment: Look again what signature you have in your constructor... It simply has its signature bounded to your first overload... By the way until c++17 you cannot deduce template parameters of a class from constructor and even then you can't deduce part of them and part left to be plated explicitly...